# DAPP WALLET transaction always fails

Tags: erc-20, dapp-development, wallet-transfer, interfaces

To improve my skills in solidity I'm working on a "wallet dapp". Based on smart contracts only, users can send ERC20 to another wallet. It works like that:

user gives the following parameters: cryptoName, amount and address where cryptoName allows my DAPP to identify the token and create an IERC20 Interface. The problem is that the function to transfer tokens sometimes works, sometimes when it's done with other ERC20 it simply doesn't work.

For example

```
function transferTokens(string cryptoName_, uint256 amount_,address address_) public {
require(tokens[cryptoName_]!= 0x0);
require(amount_ > 0);

 //// tokens[cryptoName_] will return the address of the smart contract
 //// of the ERC20 token
address contract_ = tokens[cryptoName_];
address from_ = msg.sender;

IERC20Interface = IERC20(contract_);

/// make sure user has allowed the smart contract to carry the operation
if(amount_ > IERC20Interface.allowance(from_, address(this))){
    revert();
}
/// carry transfer
IERC20Interface.transferFrom(from_, address_, amount_);

 }
```

The cryptocurrency I'm trying to transfer and it doesn't work:

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.11;


/**
 * @title SafeMath
 * @dev Math operations with safety checks that throw on error
 */
library SafeMath {
  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a * b;
    assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    return c;
  }

  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal returns (uint256) {
    // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
    uint256 c = a / b;
    // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
    return c;
  }

  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }

  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }
}

pragma solidity ^0.4.11;


/**
 * @title Ownable
 * @dev The Ownable contract has an owner address, and provides basic authorization control 
 * functions, this simplifies the implementation of "user permissions". 
 */
contract Ownable {
  address public owner;


  /** 
   * @dev The Ownable constructor sets the original `owner` of the contract to the sender
   * account.
   */
  function Ownable() {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }


  /**
   * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner. 
   */
  modifier onlyOwner() {
    if (msg.sender != owner) {
      throw;
    }
    _;
  }


  /**
   * @dev Allows the current owner to transfer control of the contract to a newOwner.
   * @param newOwner The address to transfer ownership to. 
   */
  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner {
    if (newOwner != address(0)) {
      owner = newOwner;
    }
  }

}

pragma solidity ^0.4.11;


/**
 * @title ERC20Basic
 * @dev Simpler version of ERC20 interface
 * @dev see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
 */
contract ERC20Basic {
  uint256 public totalSupply;
  function balanceOf(address who) constant returns (uint256);
  function transfer(address to, uint256 value);
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}

pragma solidity ^0.4.11;




/**
 * @title ERC20 interface
 * @dev see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
 */
contract ERC20 is ERC20Basic {
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) constant returns (uint256);
  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value);
  function approve(address spender, uint256 value);
  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

pragma solidity ^0.4.11;




/**
 * @title Basic token
 * @dev Basic version of StandardToken, with no allowances. 
 */
contract BasicToken is ERC20Basic {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  mapping(address => uint256) balances;

  /**
  * @dev transfer token for a specified address
  * @param _to The address to transfer to.
  * @param _value The amount to be transferred.
  */
  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
  }

  /**
  * @dev Gets the balance of the specified address.
  * @param _owner The address to query the the balance of. 
  * @return An uint256 representing the amount owned by the passed address.
  */
  function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
  }

}

pragma solidity ^0.4.11;




/**
 * @title Standard ERC20 token
 *
 * @dev Implementation of the basic standard token.
 * @dev https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
 * @dev Based on code by FirstBlood: https://github.com/Firstbloodio/token/blob/master/smart_contract/FirstBloodToken.sol
 */
contract StandardToken is ERC20, BasicToken {

  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;


  /**
   * @dev Transfer tokens from one address to another
   * @param _from address The address which you want to send tokens from
   * @param _to address The address which you want to transfer to
   * @param _value uint256 the amout of tokens to be transfered
   */
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) {
    var _allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];

    // Check is not needed because sub(_allowance, _value) will already throw if this condition is not met
    // if (_value > _allowance) throw;

    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = _allowance.sub(_value);
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Aprove the passed address to spend the specified amount of tokens on behalf of msg.sender.
   * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param _value The amount of tokens to be spent.
   */
  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) {

    // To change the approve amount you first have to reduce the addresses`
    //  allowance to zero by calling `approve(_spender, 0)` if it is not
    //  already 0 to mitigate the race condition described here:
    //  https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
    if ((_value != 0) && (allowed[msg.sender][_spender] != 0)) throw;

    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Function to check the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
   * @param _owner address The address which owns the funds.
   * @param _spender address The address which will spend the funds.
   * @return A uint256 specifing the amount of tokens still avaible for the spender.
   */
  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
  }

}

pragma solidity ^0.4.11;





    /**
     * @title Mintable token
     * @dev Simple ERC20 Token example, with mintable token creation
     * @dev Issue: * https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/issues/120
     * Based on code by TokenMarketNet: https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/ico/blob/master/contracts/MintableToken.sol
     */

    contract MintableToken is StandardToken, Ownable {
      event Mint(address indexed to, uint256 amount);
      event MintFinished();

      bool public mintingFinished = false;


      modifier canMint() {
        if(mintingFinished) throw;
        _;
      }

      /**
       * @dev Function to mint tokens
       * @param _to The address that will recieve the minted tokens.
       * @param _amount The amount of tokens to mint.
       * @return A boolean that indicates if the operation was successful.
       */
      function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount) onlyOwner canMint returns (bool) {
        totalSupply = totalSupply.add(_amount);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);
        Mint(_to, _amount);
        return true;
      }

      /**
       * @dev Function to stop minting new tokens.
       * @return True if the operation was successful.
       */
      function finishMinting() onlyOwner returns (bool) {
        mintingFinished = true;
        MintFinished();
        return true;
      }
    }

    pragma solidity ^0.4.11;


    /*
        Copyright 2017, Giovanni Zorzato (Boulé Foundation)
    */

    contract BouleToken is MintableToken {
        // BouleToken is an OpenZeppelin Mintable Token
        string public name = "Boule Token";
        string public symbol = "BOU";
        uint public decimals = 18;

        // do no allow to send ether to this token
        function () public payable {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

I'm constantly getting this error which makes no sense:

> transact to mySmartContract.transferTokens errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value.

I also tried to comment `require(tokens[cryptoName_]!= 0x0);
require(amount_ > 0);` and it doesn't work.

There is no point in commenting `if(amount_ > IERC20Interface.allowance(from_, address(this))){
    revert();` and this should not be the error. When manually checking balance & allowance in the ERC20 smart contract, they are both enough.

If you try it with this ERC20 however it works perfectly:

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Token {
    string public symbol = "";
    string public name = "";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
    uint256 _totalSupply = 0;
    address owner = 0;
    bool setupDone = false;

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

    mapping(address => uint256) balances;

    mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;

    function Token(address adr) {
        owner = adr;        
    }

    function SetupToken(string tokenName, string tokenSymbol, uint256 tokenSupply)
    {
        if (msg.sender == owner && setupDone == false)
        {
            symbol = tokenSymbol;
            name = tokenName;
            _totalSupply = tokenSupply * 1000000000000000000;
            balances[owner] = _totalSupply;
            setupDone = true;
        }
    }

    function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256 totalSupply) {        
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount) returns (bool success) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] >= _amount
            && _amount > 0
            && balances[_to] + _amount > balances[_to]) {
            balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
            balances[_to] += _amount;
            Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _amount);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function transferFrom(
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint256 _amount
    ) returns (bool success) {
        if (balances[_from] >= _amount
            && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _amount
            && _amount > 0
            && balances[_to] + _amount > balances[_to]) {
            balances[_from] -= _amount;
            allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _amount;
            balances[_to] += _amount;
            Transfer(_from, _to, _amount);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _amount) returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _amount;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _amount);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {
        return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between working and non-working is the return value.

- Working version returns bool

  ```
  function transferFrom(
      address _from,
      address _to,
      uint256 _amount
  ) returns (bool success) {
  ```
- Non working version does not return anything

  ```
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) {
  ```

During [EIP20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) standarization it was added to return a bool indicating if the transfer was executed. Some famous tokens were created before the finalization of the spec and do not follow it.